# Access admin controller from browser URL not working 404

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, controllers

I want to access my admin controller form browser URL i tried but its giving every time 404 page can you please help me what i am doing wrong

> http://magento.example.com/admin/namespace_quickorder/QuickorderController/index
>   http://magento.example.com/admin/quickorder/QuickorderController/index

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Quickorder>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Namespace_Quickorder>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <quickorder>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Quickorder</module>
                    <frontName>quickorder</frontName>
                </args>
            </quickorder>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <quickorder>
                    <file>quickorder.xml</file>
                </quickorder>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <quickorder>
                <class>Namespace_Quickorder_Helper</class>
            </quickorder>
        </helpers>   
        <blocks>
            <quickorder>
                <class>Namespace_Quickorder_Block</class>
            </quickorder>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <quickorder>
                <class>Namespace_Quickorder_Model</class>
                    <resourceModel>quickorder_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </quickorder>
            <quickorder_mysql4>
                <class>Namespace_Quickorder_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <quickorder>
                        <table>quickorder</table>
                    </quickorder>
                </entities>
            </quickorder_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <quickorder_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_Quickorder</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </quickorder_setup>
            <quickorder_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </quickorder_write>
            <quickorder_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </quickorder_read>
        </resources>
   </global> 
   <admin>
            <routers>
                <quickorder>
                    <use>admin</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Namespace_Quickorder</module>
                        <frontName>quickorder</frontName>
                    </args>
                </quickorder>
            </routers>
            </admin><adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <quickorder module="quickorder">
                <title>Quickorder</title>
                <sort_order>80</sort_order>
                <children>
                <quickorder module="quickorder">
                        <title>Manage Quickorder</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <action>quickorder/adminhtml_quickorder</action>
                    </quickorder>
                </children>
            </quickorder>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <quickorder translate="title" module="quickorder">
                            <title>Quickorder</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <quickorderbackend translate="title">
                                    <title>Free Catalog</title>
                                </quickorderbackend><quickorder translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Quickorder</title>
                                </quickorder>
                            </children>
                       </quickorder>
                    </children>
                </admin>

            </resources>
        </acl>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <quickorder>
                    <file>quickorder.xml</file>
                </quickorder>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

Admin Controller :

```
<?php

class Namespace_Quickorder_Adminhtml_QuickorderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction() 
    {
        die('dddddddddddd');
        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Controller` is not used in the URL.  Try `http://magento.example.com/admin/quickorder/Quickorder`

Answer (score 0):

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Quickorder>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Namespace_Quickorder>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <quickorder>
                <class>Namespace_Quickorder_Helper</class>
            </quickorder>
        </helpers>   
        <blocks>
            <quickorder>
                <class>Namespace_Quickorder_Block</class>
            </quickorder>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <quickorder>
                <class>Namespace_Quickorder_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>quickorder_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </quickorder>
            <quickorder_mysql4>
                <class>Namespace_Quickorder_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <quickorder>
                        <table>quickorder</table>
                    </quickorder>
                </entities>
            </quickorder_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <quickorder_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_Quickorder</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </quickorder_setup>
            <quickorder_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </quickorder_write>
            <quickorder_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </quickorder_read>
        </resources>
    </global> 
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <quickorder>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Quickorder</module>
                    <frontName>quickorder</frontName>
                </args>
            </quickorder>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <quickorder>
                    <file>quickorder.xml</file>
                </quickorder>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
   <admin>
       <routers>
           <quickorder>
               <use>admin</use>
               <args>
                   <module>Namespace_Quickorder</module>
                   <frontName>quickorder</frontName>
               </args>
           </quickorder>
       </routers>
   </admin>
<adminhtml>
   <menu>
       <quickorder module="quickorder">
           <title>Quickorder</title>
           <sort_order>80</sort_order>
           <children>
               <quickorder module="quickorder">
                   <title>Manage Quickorder</title>
                   <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                   <action>quickorder/adminhtml_quickorder</action>
               </quickorder>
           </children>
       </quickorder>
   </menu>
   <acl>
       <resources>
           <all>
               <title>Allow Everything</title>
           </all>
           <admin>
               <children>
                   <quickorder translate="title" module="quickorder">
                       <title>Quickorder</title>
                       <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                       <children>
                           <quickorderbackend translate="title">
                               <title>Free Catalog</title>
                           </quickorderbackend>
                           <quickorder translate="title">
                               <title>Manage Quickorder</title>
                           </quickorder>
                        </children>
                    </quickorder>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <quickorder>
                <file>quickorder.xml</file>
            </quickorder>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

**Adminhtml/QuickorderController.php**

```
class Namespace_Quickorder_Adminhtml_QuickorderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction() 
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Now if you type `www.domaine.com/index.php/admin/quickorder/index` you will load your layout

**Nb:** The Url is composed like this :

```
www.domaine.com/index.php/{adminfrontName}/{controllerName}/{actionName}
```

> Dont forget to check your layout! `quickorder.xml` it's very important otherwise if you have some error on it, 
>   you will not render it.